# Must a Wizard prepare a spell to cast it as a ritual?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, spellcasting, rituals

Ritual casting does **not** expend a spell slot, I know that. However, the Wizard class feature does not say anything about whether you must prepare the subject spell to cast it as a ritual. On one side, it is anyway "casting" a spell, so you can say "yes, you must prepare." On the other hand, (although it is just about how wizards cast rituals,) your ritual involves your spellbook, so you can see the ritual ceremony "from the spellbook", which removes the need to prepare the spell.

My question is: Must I prepare the subject spell in advance to perform it?

This is only about **Wizards**. Clerics, Druids, Bards have these problems nailed down *explicitly.* Clerics' and Druids' ritual casting requires you to **prepare the spell in advance**, and Bards' rituals can **only be drawn from what they know**.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### No, per the Wizard's [Ritual Casting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#ClassFeatures) feature (PHB, pg. 114):

> **Ritual Casting**
>
> You can cast a wizard spell as a ritual if that spell has the ritual tag and you have the spell in your spellbook. You don’t need to have the spell prepared.

Comment: To add to that, PHB p. 201-202 reads: (...) The ritual version of a spell takes 10 minutes longer to cast than normal. (...) The caster must also have the spell prepared or on his or her list of spells known, unless the character’s ritual feature specifies otherwise, **as the wizard’s does.** 

My version of the Wizard's Ritual Casting: (PHB p. 114) You can cast a wizard spell as a ritual if that spell has the ritual tag and you have the spell in your spellbook. **You don't need to have the spell prepared**